# Septic Inspection Pipe crooked in field

Tags: septic, inspection

Hope you can help maybe.   Our Septic ( built 2009 ) is a mound system, but installed in a depressed area of the property so it doesn't really look like one.  After the recent torrent of rain we've had in New Jersey I noticed one of the inspection ports is crooked and there's a hole next to the pvc pipe.  Looking down with a flashlight I notice that it has a vertical crack.   ( see Pic ) .

Thinking of digging it out and patching or replacing the broken section.   Any wisdom for this project?  Why do we think that it made itself crooked?  Only theory I have heard is the ground shifted a little.   Could this theory hold water?

What would you do?   Thanks in advance.[image]